# How to use regular expressions (\b, \w) in Freemarker?

Tags: regex, freemarker

```
${str?replace("\d+", "", "r")};
```

I wanted to use `\d` to remove numbers, but it didn't work!!!

But `${str?replace("[0-9]", "", "r")};` works!!!

So, I wanna know how to use regex like `\d`, `\b`, `\w`, etc?

Comment: It seems that `freemaker` is a java based template engine. So why don't you try `\\d+`?

Comment: It not just silently "doesn't work", it gives you a parsing error message... I mean, next time include the error messages if something fails.

Comment: @ddekany Yeah, you are right, there's a error message when using \d

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to double the backslashes:

```
${str?replace("\\d+", "", "r")};
```

This is because string escaping rules are applied before regex escaping rules. So the string `"\\d"` is translated to the regex `\d` which then matches a digit.

If your string is `"\d"`, the string processor translates it to a literal `d` (because `\d` is not a recognized string escape sequence, so it's ignored).

Comment: BTW, FreeMarker doesn't translate `\d` to `d`; it gives a parsing error message.

Comment: `"\\d+"` can be written as `r"\d+"`, where the `r` stands for "raw", not regexp. In raw strings backslashes aren't special, which makes them practical for regular expressions.

Comment: Would be lovely if the Freemarker docs actually documented this! Thanks!